# Remove broken Ubuntu partition on macOS

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, partition, catalina, dual-boot

I started with partitioning my MacBook Pro for using Ubuntu and macOS. The ubuntu-partition is kinda broken so I want to delete the partition. I tried to do this though disk utilities, but I cannot delete the ubuntu-partition or change the size. I even tried in recovery mode but still cannot delete the partition.

I cannot see the disk on the sidebar. Only when I click on partition-button to see all the partitions.

Are there other ways to remove the partition to get one macintosh hardrive?

Comment: Edit your question and add the output from `diskutil list`.